# CSS - Relative positioned div overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a basic layout with a block of text above and below and image like this..

```css
 .image_holder img {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
    .image_holder{position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tellus mauris, pharetra a ligula ut, aliquam accumsan sem. Etiam semper, mauris vel congue laoreet, tellus quam ultrices mi, vel fringilla magna tortor eu massa. Phasellus aliquet semper lacus. Nullam vehicula purus non nunc facilisis tincidunt posuere ut lacus. In viverra viverra bibendum. Sed placerat mollis scelerisque. Sed ultricies diam ut velit ornare molestie. Nam commodo elit lorem, vel fringilla dui venenatis non. Duis condimentum nisl ut risus egestas malesuada. In at accumsan ex. Curabitur quis magna sodales, laoreet dui nec, ullamcorper libero. Integer rhoncus, magna non rutrum scelerisque, leo odio ornare sapien, a ullamcorper nunc urna a risus. Duis sit amet diam sollicitudin, condimentum enim nec, ullamcorper erat.
</div>

<div class="image_holder" style="position:relative;">
    <img id="image1" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
</div>
 
<div class="test2">
    Quisque pulvinar sapien ipsum, a dapibus nulla auctor venenatis. Etiam pretium nec mauris eu dictum. Maecenas et sollicitudin orci. Etiam mattis tincidunt lacus, malesuada imperdiet quam consequat non. Aliquam ex lorem, pulvinar ac egestas nec, rutrum et elit. Duis vitae semper mauris. Curabitur sem sapien, accumsan quis risus a, dictum feugiat tellus. Donec vitae pulvinar orci. Duis dapibus odio ut luctus congue. Praesent egestas orci eget tortor aliquam fermentum. Donec mollis et tellus eget ullamcorper.
</div>
```

Why does the div below overlap the image?  As the images are absolutley positioned inside a relativley positioned div then it wouldn't break layout?

Comment: The div isn't inflated by the image because it is absolute, so it "looks" like a point for others divs. the img takes just the position by its parent

Comment: `it wouldn't break layout` Yes, it wouldn't break the layout, because your div is relative positioned. So, your image is absolute to div only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define **height** and / or **width** for the **relative** position because once you give an element **absolute** its getting out of the flow so you have to set the **height** and **width** **100%** to the absolute then and its looking for a parent that have a height and width to behave in the right way

```css
 .image_holder img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
 .image_holder {
    position:relative; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tellus mauris, pharetra a ligula ut, aliquam accumsan sem. Etiam semper, mauris vel congue laoreet, tellus quam ultrices mi, vel fringilla magna tortor eu massa. Phasellus aliquet semper lacus. Nullam vehicula purus non nunc facilisis tincidunt posuere ut lacus. In viverra viverra bibendum. Sed placerat mollis scelerisque. Sed ultricies diam ut velit ornare molestie. Nam commodo elit lorem, vel fringilla dui venenatis non. Duis condimentum nisl ut risus egestas malesuada. In at accumsan ex. Curabitur quis magna sodales, laoreet dui nec, ullamcorper libero. Integer rhoncus, magna non rutrum scelerisque, leo odio ornare sapien, a ullamcorper nunc urna a risus. Duis sit amet diam sollicitudin, condimentum enim nec, ullamcorper erat.
</div>

<div class="image_holder" style="position:relative; height: 300px; width: 300px">
    <img id="image1" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
</div>
 
<div class="test2">
    Quisque pulvinar sapien ipsum, a dapibus nulla auctor venenatis. Etiam pretium nec mauris eu dictum. Maecenas et sollicitudin orci. Etiam mattis tincidunt lacus, malesuada imperdiet quam consequat non. Aliquam ex lorem, pulvinar ac egestas nec, rutrum et elit. Duis vitae semper mauris. Curabitur sem sapien, accumsan quis risus a, dictum feugiat tellus. Donec vitae pulvinar orci. Duis dapibus odio ut luctus congue. Praesent egestas orci eget tortor aliquam fermentum. Donec mollis et tellus eget ullamcorper.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height on "image_holder" since it gets a height of 0px. You can easily see this in Developer Tools in your browser. An element gets its height from its content and since the content of image_holder (the image that is) is positioned absolute it will not add the the height of the parent. You need to set the height manually in this case, but for a simple layout as this you should probably not use position: absolute.

Comment: The image is dynamic though so the height can not be fixed

Comment: @fightstarr20 Then why would you want this exact layout with an image positioned absolute? This is how position absolute work. You can always set overflow: none if you don't want the image to flow outsite its parent but I don't think that's what you're after. Can you describe what you want the layout to look like?